# jquery validation onblur without any input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, plugins

i am new to jQuery validation plugin ,i need to use this plugin to achieve the following:
step1: the user click a input control and he just do nothing
step2: change the focus of the input control
step3: trigger the onblur event then validate and give him a hint that this field is required

i think the above task is very simple but when i use this plugin to do the validation,i get
in trouble ,because there is nothing happen,then i reference the official document that said when there is nothing input the plugin will ignore any validation method and just do nothing.and i try to set up the onfocusout configuration to true in the validate method but
there just nothing happen
how should i change the configuration to get what i want,is there anybody encounter this kind of problem? any advise is appreciated!

here is my code:

html code:

```
<div>
  <form id="test" method="get" action="#">
    username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
     password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
      <input type="submit" value="login"/>
 </form>
</div>
```

js code:

```
<script>
  $("#test").validate({
     debug:true,
     rules:{
       username:{
          required:true
       },
        password:{
          required:true
       }   
     },
     messages:{
       username:{
           required:"this field is required!"    
       },
        password:{
           required:"this field is required!"    
       }
     }
  })
</script>
```